# Medical Record History

Tags: medical-records

Example: In college, my records are essentially made such that I have to turn all past records in before applying to a new school.

It has been 5+ years since I have met with a medical professional and not being a doctor I really don't remember what cholesterol and other health problems I had.

Is there a way to go back and retrieve all past records.  I gather after 10 years or so they may no longer have them, but I have yet to have determined a way to get all past records.

Comment: All you can do is call the practices where you were seen and ask. They should have kept records at least 7 years in the US. Rules may be different in other countries.

Comment: Assuming this question meets sites standards and your answer is correct you are welcome to post that as an answer.

Comment: @CareyGregory Doesn't my insurance have something.  I have heard they use codes or something sometimes.

Comment: They will know what tests and procedures they paid for, but they won't know the results. And, really, getting information from an insurance company is going to be 3.2 million times harder than getting it from a doctor's office. It's not hard. Just call them and ask. Expect to pay a small fee for copies. Meanwhile, you could just schedule a routine physical with another doctor and get current results. Your lab tests from 5+ years ago aren't likely to be valuable information.

Comment: Okay so it sounds like the best answer is that the insurance company may have who I meet with and the doctor offices the actual data.

Comment: Yeah, maybe. Good luck with the insurance companies.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should see a GP more often then once every 5+ years. This will prevent such things in the future because if you have a "standard" GP, they have access to your medical history anyways. If your one of the few lucky that never get sick, it still doesn't hurt to get check-ups as to not overlook minor changes with great effects...